Is this money halal
In my matric result I got 1077 marks out of 1100, after getting these numbers my uncle gave me 10000 Rupees as a gift on congratulating me on getting good marks. The problem is that as far as I believe out of these 1077 approximately 5 to 10 marks or required by cheating, so is this many Halal for me. My sister and my cousin also got number also got good numbers in different classes but not  as high percentage as me birthday still they got the gift money from my uncle as a gift what should I do. Majority of the numbers are acquired by Halal means but 5 to 10  numbers are as far as I believe acquired by cheating. Please guide me is this money halal for me?
